# how to extract multiple words from sentence that have same ending to a new column separated by commas

Tags: microsoft-excel, string-manipulation

I have an issue whereby for example i have a sentence in column A that says for "hello ID users tbzoo, rjkth, mnkz, plzoo, rtzoo and fghzt" and i would like to create a new column B that extracts all the words in column A that end with zoo and are separated by a comma eg column B would have tbzoo,plzoo,trzoo.
So far the formula i have come up with using MID and search only returns the first word that ends in zoo and not all of them.
Please help!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The key here might be to split your string into an array of words. Having ExcelO365 you could use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('zoo') +1) = 'zoo']"))
```

[image]

It'll also work in Excel 2019 if entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Needless to say that you'd need more nested `SUBSTITUTE()` if one has more type of punctuation at the end of words. Also, keep in mind `XPATH` is case-sensitive!

If you want to know more about this `FILTERXML()` function, maybe have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194).

If you do not have access to `TEXTJOIN()`, I guess you can resort to PowerQuery or VBA.